# What etiquette / preconditions exist before posting an answer?

Tags: discussion

Someone recently down-voted my answer to a question after I posted it and it was accepted.  The person who down-voted me had asked for clarification in a comment...

> Can you show what have you tried? Any reference?

I saw the comment, but didn't think much of it and went on to answer.  Later, they down-voted my answer and left this comment...

> You should first let OP to provide some reference of effort.

**Does this mean that we should not provide answers until the person asking the question has expressed that they really have tried to do it and failed?**  I feel like I've seen *MANY* useful answers where the original question didn't include someone making such a claim.  Is it really appropriate to down-vote them?

**While we're on the subject, are there other pre-conditions that should be followed before answering?**  It seems that answers get posted with incredible speed on stackoverflow with many of the questions having precious little to go on.  Perhaps these preconditions need to be made more obvious and / or better enforced by the community.

---

In case it is true that one must demonstrate effort before getting a question answered, I hereby formally declare that I have searched for the answer to this question using both google's site search functionality and StackExchange's own search capabilities.  I have not found an adequate answer.  (How's that for "meta"?)

Comment: People can down vote for any reason they want. Best not to dwell on it too much. telling them they shouldn't down vote for the reason they did is fighting a losing battle.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/how-should-you-respond-to-give-me-a-fish-rtfm-questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it was a bad question, because the user had shown no effort, and expected someone to simply give them the code. The single sentence was also poorly written, and it's really unclear what they're asking.  That particular question probably won't benefit anyone else down the road the way it stands now.

SO prefers good answers to *good* questions since the goal is to help **others** looking for answers in the future, not merely to help the OP now.

A good answer left on a *bad* question makes it hard to get rid of the bad question (which gets down voted, closed and eventually deleted).

Some may even say/vote that there's no good answer for a bad question. It only encourages questions that aren't generally useful, and once someone has an answer, they have no incentive to improve their question.

Comment: So, what I'm hearing is that the only pre-condition for an answer is a good question. Is that right? Also, what about improving the question after the fact? Is that an option?

Comment: If you can improve a question, beforehand would be better,  to avoid down votes and comments, as in your situation. But after is fine.